# SQL - Inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have an query as following:

```
SELECT t1.onderzoeksNR, t1.antwoorden as b1_m1_v1_items, t1.commentaar as b1_m1_v1_toe, t2.antwoorden as b1_m1_v2_items, t2.commentaar as b1_m1_v2_toe
FROM antwoorden t1
INNER JOIN antwoorden t2
ON t1.onderzoeksNR = t2.onderzoeksNR
WHERE t1.behandeltraject = 1 AND t1.meting = 1 AND t1.vragenlijst = 1
AND t2.behandeltraject = 1 AND t2.meting = 1 AND t2.vragenlijst = 2
```

What this will output is this:

[image: Result of above query]

This is exactly what I want.

**However, the problem is this:**

If I add another inner join

```
inner join antwoorden t3 
on t1.onderzoeksNR = t3.onderzoeksNR
```

but then like:

`t3.behandeltraject = 1 AND t3.meting = 2 AND t3.vragenlijst = 1`

The query will give back 0 records.

Obviously, this is because there are **no rows** in `antwoorden` containing the asked properties.

(`t3.behandeltraject = 1 AND t3.meting = 2 AND t3.vragenlijst = 1`)

My questions:

1. How can I still retrieve what I had in the beginning,
2. And then add the inner join `antwoorden t3` to it, but then with empty values (if no rows with `t3.behandeltraject = 1 AND t3.meting = 2 AND t3.vragenlijst = 1` are found)?

To illustrate what I mean:

[image: Desired result]

Instead of 0 records returning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` and you need to move some `WHERE` criteria into the `JOIN` criteria:

```
SELECT t1.onderzoeksNR, t1.antwoorden as b1_m1_v1_items, t1.commentaar as b1_m1_v1_toe, t2.antwoorden as b1_m1_v2_items, t2.commentaar as b1_m1_v2_toe
FROM antwoorden t1
INNER JOIN antwoorden t2
ON t1.onderzoeksNR = t2.onderzoeksNR
LEFT JOIN antwoorden t3 ON t1.onderzoeksNR = t3.onderzoeksNR
     AND t3.behandeltraject = 1 AND t3.meting = 2 AND t3.vragenlijst = 1
WHERE t1.behandeltraject = 1 AND t1.meting = 1 AND t1.vragenlijst = 1
AND t2.behandeltraject = 1 AND t2.meting = 1 AND t2.vragenlijst = 2
```

`LEFT JOIN` will allow for records in your first two tables to return regardless of whether they `JOIN` to `t3`, but if you use `WHERE` criteria to filter records where `t3.meting = 2`, etc. you'll remove results.  Moving that `WHERE` criteria into the `JOIN` will return the same records as your initial query, just `NULL` for every column from `t3` you add in, since none meet the criteria.

Comment: Beat me to `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE` thing.)

Comment: Thank you sir, this helped me out. I need to do 8 left joins, and if it would only return data when all criteria was met, I would never get any data back.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in the last one :

```
LEFT JOIN antwoorden t3 ON t1.onderzoeksNR = t3.onderzoeksNR
```

Comment: Well actually this doesn't solve my problem. It still returns 0 rows, with `inner join`, or `left outer join`.

Comment: @JiFus : Try to remove conditions from `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.