# Inner join return duplicates data which does not exist in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute this it return more than million rows, in first table I have 315 000 rows, in second about 14 000. What should I do to get all rows from both tables? Also if I don't stop server it breakdown during listing unexcited rows.

```
select * 
from tblNormativiIspratnica 
inner join tblNormativiSubIspratnica on tblNormativiIspratnica.ZaklucokBroj = tblNormativiSubIspratnica.ZaklucokBroj
```

Comment: Title and question are unclear to me and your sentence has bad grammar. Please improve your post. You may also add three example code blocks with dummy data of table 1 and 2 and of the join result.

Comment: You may also [use the search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]+inner+join). Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888412/sql-inner-join) may guide you too.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the first table has 315000 rows and the second one has 14000 rows, then the fields that you are using are not forming part of a good primary-key-foreign-key relationship, with the result you are getting cartesian product duplicates. If you want to have a well-defined result, you must have well-defined fields that serve these purposes. btw, Take care of your server-breakdown etc, do not try queries that fetch large resultsets, if you have no idea what you are doing. Quickly look-up the basics, and understand the design, by writing simple queries with more specific criteria that fetch small resultsets, before you run large ones. 
If you do not have issues of server performance and breaking down, I would have suggested DISTINCT as a (poor) quick solution for getting unique rows, but remember, DISTINCT queries can, at times, take a performance toll.